# advice on the stellar toml

Tags: stellar.toml

May I have more then one asset in a toml file? We have our actually asset for the business and then we have a donation token that will be used to help other organizations, We cant have two toml files but can we have two assest on one toml one url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add as many [[CURRENCIES]] blocks as you want. The double brackets indicate an "Array of Tables" type in toml, so it will be parsed as an array of currencies.

Besides, you can check your stellar.toml here: https://stellar.sui.li/

```
[[CURRENCIES]]
code = "NaCl"
issuer = "GCSALT7P5DEWLYQSUIQVNIFOYEZH3FFLQ3YBDHAREFMEZLLEWYFW5JZU"
...

[[CURRENCIES]]
code = "BTC"
issuer = "GCSALT7P5DEWLYQSUIQVNIFOYEZH3FFLQ3YBDHAREFMEZLLEWYFW5JZU"
...

[[CURRENCIES]]
...
```

Comment: Thank you that is perfect Ill go so that now